# adding a python string with a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string of numbers like this:

```
line
Out[2]: '1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
```

I have a numpy array of numbers like this:

```
rpm
Out[3]:
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

I'd like to add the line of numbers in the string to the numbers in the array, and keep the result in the array.

Is there a simple/elegant way to do this using numpy or python?

Comment: are these two array of difference shape?

Comment: `np.array(line.split(','),int)` also works - giving `array` a list of strings and telling it to interpret them as ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html).

```
import numpy as np

line = '1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'
res = np.fromstring(line, dtype=int, sep=',')
print(res)
```

Output:

```
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])
```

Comment: thank you very much, this works well.  I was looking at map and where and other functions, and glad to see there is a fromstring() function.